# How do you create masonry layout with divs of specific widths and heights?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to achieve a layout that looks like this:

[image]

It's a `grid` of `7` images with differing widths and heights, in specific positions.

Currently, I have the following:

```css
.imageGrid {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: #FFEE7E;
}
.imageGrid__grid {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 12px;
  width: 100%;
/*   grid-template-columns: masonry;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px); */
}
.imageGrid__gridItem {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.imageGrid__gridItem--1 {
  height: 757px;
  width: 505px;
}
.imageGrid__gridItem--2 {
  width: 236px;
  height: 317px;
}
.imageGrid__gridItem--3 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 317px;
}
.imageGrid__gridItem--4 {
  width: 379px;
  height: 569px;
}
.imageGrid__gridItem--5 {
  width: 580px;
  height: 386px;
}
.imageGrid__gridItem--6 {
  width: 582px;
  height: 232px;
}
.imageGrid__gridItem--7 {
  width: 191px;
  height: 277px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<section class="imageGrid">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
        <div class="imageGrid__intro">
          <h2 class="imageGrid__header">This is the header</h2>
          <p class="imageGrid__copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="imageGrid__grid">

            <div class="imageGrid__gridItem imageGrid__gridItem--1" loading="lazy" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="imageGrid__gridItem imageGrid__gridItem--2" loading="lazy" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="imageGrid__gridItem imageGrid__gridItem--3" loading="lazy" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="imageGrid__gridItem imageGrid__gridItem--4" loading="lazy" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="imageGrid__gridItem imageGrid__gridItem--5" loading="lazy" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="imageGrid__gridItem imageGrid__gridItem--6" loading="lazy" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="imageGrid__gridItem imageGrid__gridItem--7" loading="lazy" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

However, I'm unsure how to proceed following this. I've scoured `codepen` and other sandboxes, but cannot see a masonry layout like my screenshot depicts in those demos.

In my demo, parts of my image get added onto the next column also. Is a grid system the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The widths seem unrelated to each other but as they are all known have you thought of just positioning each element in it's correct place independently?

Comment: @AHaworth - Are you suggesting `absolute` positioning each grid item?

Comment: If there were more of a relationship between the widths of the elements and between the heights I might suggest grid template areas. But as it is you might as well position each one individually. It’s very non responsive but that’s built in by having fixed dimensions and subtle differences like a width of 580 above a width of 582.

Comment: Learn grid which makes it easy, or install masonry

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your elements into 2 columns. Header and items 1-2-3 on the left and others on the right. Then give negative margin-top your right column.

To prevent image overflowing you can use

```
img{
    width:100%;
    height:100;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```